# Google Map control displays but no mapping content

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, jquery-mobile

i am passing long / lat values as url paramaters on the page and i can see them being read correctly when i use the alert function

however for some reason the map control loads but the map remains blank

can anyone see where i have gone wrong

this has been a long standing problem i have spent many weeks comming back to without success

the code i am using is as follows

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Map</title>
            <script>

               function gup(name) {
                   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                                         var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
                                         var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                                         var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
                                         if (results == null)
                                         return "";
                                         else
                                         return results[1];
                                         }
                    var latlong=(gup('q'));
                                 //  alert(latlong);


                function initialize() {
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlong);
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 16,
                        center: myLatlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }
                    var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( "map_canvas" ), myOptions );

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myLatlng,
                        map: map,
                        center: myLatlng,
                        title: 'Hello World!'
                        });
                }
            </script>
            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <style>
                html {
                    height: 100%;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #map_canvas { 
                height: 100%;
            }    
            </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">

        <div id="map_canvas"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `google.maps.LatLng()` expects 2 arguments, latitude and longitude, but you pass only 1 argument

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same exact error, and I knew it was caused by the `overflow:hidden;`.

Maybe this works for you:

```
div[id^=map_canvas], 
div[id^=map_canvas] div {overflow: auto;}
```

all the credit to ["ScottS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188761/css-overflow-hidden-property-causing-problems-with-google-map-api)

Comment: Just tested the code provided in the Question and the solution is the one [provided by Dr.Molle in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795801/google-map-control-displays-but-no-mapping-content/23866076?noredirect=1#comment31178334_20795801). Your CSS actually makes *everything* disappear :/

Comment: :( I cri, hopefully the person from the question will see Dr.Molle response :) gj @brasofilo. I have no time to test the code, working...     Although the answer didn't worked for me.